# How do i have my python program restart to a certain line?

Tags: python

```
print ("Enter the object you are tyring to find.")
print ("1 = Radius")
print ("2 = Arch Length")
print ("3 = Degree")
print ("4 = Area")
x = int(input("(1,2,3,4):"))
if x == 1:
    print ("You are finding the Radius.")
    ra = int(input("Enter the arch length: "))
    rd = int(input("Enter the degree: "))
    rr = ra/math.radians(rd)
    print ("The Radius is:",rr)
if x == 2:
    print ("You are finding the Arch Length.")
    sr = int(input("Enter the radius: "))
    sd = int(input("Enter the degree: "))
    ss = math.radians(sd)*sr
    print ("The Arch Length is:",ss)
```

I am making a basic math program but i want it to repeat infinitely. This is not the complete code but i want to do the same thing for the rest of the "if" statements. i want it to end after each function is completed and repeat back to the first line. thanks!

Comment: it seems work for a loop

Answer (score 2):

Put a

```
while True:
```

at the spot you want to restart from; indent all following lines four spaces each.

At every point in which you want to restart from just after the `while`, add the statement:

```
continue
```

properly indented also, of course.

If you also want to offer the user a chance to end the program cleanly (e.g with yet another choice besides the 4 you're now offering), then at that spot have a conditional statement (again properly indented):

```
if whateverexitcondition:
    break
```

Comment: instead of continue it might be better to use an elif structure

Comment: @DoodyP, "flat is better than nested" (`import this` at a Python interpreter prompt) -- `continue`, `break`, and `return`, can flatten the code and thus improve it, compared to nested tests.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to add a way to let the user quit and break the loop but a while True will loop as long as you want.

```
while True:
     # let user decide if they want to continue or quit
    x = input("Pick a number from (1,2,3,4) or enter 'q' to quit:")
    if x == "q":
        print("Goodbye")
        break
    x = int(x)   
    if x == 1:
        print ("You are finding the Radius.")
        ra = int(input("Enter the arch length: "))
        rd = int(input("Enter the degree: "))
        rr = ra/math.radians(rd)
        print ("The Radius is:",rr)
    elif x == 2: # use elif, x cannot be 1 and 2
        print ("You are finding the Arch Length.")
        sr = int(input("Enter the radius: "))
        sd = int(input("Enter the degree: "))
        ss = math.radians(sd)*sr
        print ("The Arch Length is:",ss)
    elif x == 3:
       .....
    elif x == 4:
       .....
```

If you are going to use a loop you can also verify that the user inputs only valid input using a try/except:

```
while True:
    try:
       x = int(input("(1,2,3,4):"))
    except ValueError:
        print("not a number")
        continue
```